# import the oracle dump programatically through java??

Tags: jdbc

is there a way to import the oracle dump through java program? If yes, How?

Answer (score 0):

Both yes and no.  It's not possible through JDBC which is what I think you are asking.

It is possible using `Runtime.exec()` to call the command line Oracle command to import the dump.